# I have a string which contains a decimal point e.g. "10.00" and I want to hide it using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string which contains a decimal point e.g.  "10.00" and I want to hide it using jQuery? I need to trim it to "10" from "10.00".

Comment: Any edge-cases you need to ask about? For example values less than 1, e.g. `0.23`, `.23`, `0`, `-0.23` or `-23`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many options, I'd probably go with

```
var foo = "10.00";

foo.split('.')[ 0 ];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Math.floor(parseInt("10.00",10));
// 10
```

If you need it back as a string rather than an int,

```
Math.floor(parseInt("10.00",10)).toString(); 
// "10"
```

#### Edit:

Actually, `Math.floor()` isn't necessary. `parseInt()` will do it alone:

```
parseInt("10.00",10).toString();
// "10"
```

Comment: Do you need the `Math.floor` here, won't `parseInt` return an integer value?

Comment: @Michael, won't `parseInt("10.00", 10)).toString();` do the trick?

Comment: @Konerak nothing, Math.floor doesn't take an integer value. Even if it does, the number will look exactly the same. `parseInt` is all he needs.

Comment: @XyanEwing Works great, but then we'll get a question back of _what does the operator ~~ do?_

Comment: @XyanEwing it's groovy, but the potential for confusion is immense!

Comment: @davegrove But it's so _pretty_!

Answer (score 1):

The following will remove the decimal values by converting it to an integer:

```
// Returns an int of 10.
var myInteger = parseInt("10.00");
```

or

```
// Returns a string of "10".
var myString = parseInt("10.00").toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Or the regex way. Since we start with a String and want a String out, why bother converting back and forth to numbers ? And this will be faster than 'split'.

```
/[^\.]*/.exec("10.00")[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Pure string way to do this is

```
var Trim = function( n ) {
    var index = n.indexOf('.');
    return n.substring(0, index - 1);
};

//usage
Trim( "10.00" );
```

Answer (score 0):

The following may be useful:

```
intvalue = parseInt($('#quantity').val(), 10);
```